# Shared Preferences in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sharedpreferences

I have tried to save login value as true if user has logged in once by using

```
Application.Current.Properties["isLoggedIn"] = "true";
```

but its not working. If i remove my app from background it again shows the login page but if user is logged in it should show the next page.

Comment: Have a look at the [settings plug](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) from [james montemagno](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3085228/jamesmontemagno)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32271446/4654957

Answer (score 4):

When using 'Application Properties Dictionary' you have to keep in mind few things:

- According to the official documentation: 'The Properties dictionary is saved to the device automatically'. However, if you want to ensure persistence you have to explicitly call `SavePropertiesAsync()`.
- The Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for storage. Attempting to store other types such as List can fail silently.

Read the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) carefully and pay attention to details.
 Here is a code example:

```
private async Task SaveApplicationProperty<T>(string key, T value)
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties[key] = value;
    await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}

private T LoadApplicationProperty<T>(string key)
{
    return (T) Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties[key];
}

// To save your property
await SaveApplicationProperty("isLoggedIn", true);

// To load your property
bool isLoggedIn = LoadApplicationProperty<bool>("isLoggedIn");
```

Base on your needs you may consider [Local Database](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/) or [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) instead. However for saving just a few primitive values `Application Properties` approach should be good enough.

Comment: where i have to use it??

Comment: Right after 'Application.Current.Properties["isLoggedIn"] = "true";' for example.

Comment: Its not working after that its again showing login page if i remove my app from background

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'i remove my app from background' but if you await 'SavePropertiesAsync()' right after setting your value it should work, unless the app is killed in the middle of 'SavePropertiesAsync()' or uninstalled.

Comment: remove my app from background means if i kill my app. so when i will come to know that it has SavePropertiesAysnc() so that i can kill my app

Comment: how to call this method with "isloggedin" as key and true as value

Comment: it is showing error "An object reference is required for non-static field,method or property" in the line calling await SaveApplicationProperty("isLoggedIn", true);

Comment: I had a typo in the loading part, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Forms now includes Xamarin Forms Essentials and contains the Preferences component that you need. Check out the official website and try it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=ios

**This is an example of how to manage preferences with Essentials.**

- To save a value for a given key in preferences:

  `Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");`
- To retrieve a value from preferences or a default if not set:

  `var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");`
- To remove the key from preferences:

  `Preferences.Remove("my_key");`
- To remove all preferences:

  `Preferences.Clear();`

**Supported Data Types:**

- bool
- double
- int
- float
- long
- string
- DateTime

Answer (score 1):

First we set the key and value using below code

Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set("UserId", content.userId);

We can get the above value in any page of project using below code

Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("UserId", "");