# List does not get saved when I use Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently trying to save a list in Xamarin forms. I use this code snippet:

```
var list = new List<myClass> ();

Application.Current.Properties["myList"] = list;
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

When I then close the app and use this code...

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myList"))
{

}
```

...I cannot reach this if statement.

I read something about people having issues saving a list with this solution but they solved it by converting it to a string. I am a bit unsure on how to do this. If I do this...

```
Application.Current.Properties["myList"] = list.ToString();
```

...the app crashes.

I saw that there is a plugin called "Settings" that I might need to use instead in case there isn't a solution to this problem but I would prefer to work with my current code if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for
>   storage. Attempting to store other types (such as List can
>   fail silently).

It means that you can't save `List` because it's not a primitive type of object. 
You can serialize it to JSON string for example then it will work. 
Code example:

```
var jsonValueToSave = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
Application.Current.Properties["myList"] = jsonValueToSave;
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Don't forget to deserialize JSON to `List<string>` when loading the value back.

Note that `yourList.ToString()` will not work in this case. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).

P.S.: Get familiar with the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) & check this post on another [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43503918/1970317).

Comment: I tried with this code: `var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    Application.Current.Properties["myList"] = content;
    await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();` but it does not change the outcome

Comment: HttpContent is not a primitive type, that's why it's not working. Serializing to JSON string is enough. I updated my answer with code example.

Comment: HttpContent is not a "primitive type". You have to serialize the List to a String

Comment: Alright! Seems to work now :) Awesome. I am a bit unsure on how to get the value out now though, with this code: `foreach (var data in Application.Current.Properties["myList"] as List<MyClass>)` I get a crash `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: You have not a List<MyClass> saved in your Property. You have a "String". So you have to deserialize the String to a List<MyClass> then do the "foreach"

Comment: You have to deserialize JSON string to List<string>, something like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(Application.Current.Properties["myList"])

Comment: awesome! thanks for the help guys! I did this to deserialize the json: `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myClass>>(Application.Current.Properties["myList"].ToString());` and it seems to work very well

Comment: I kept losing my stored properties and this was the reason why. The documentation should just mention what types of objects you can store so you can't make this mistake. I was just storing a simple class with strings and integers. No list or whatever.